# getting a list of children recursively out of db with Id and parent ID

Tags: recursion, openjpa

I am writing a function that will when you throw it an ID you are supposed to get all the children and grandchildren of this particular id... I am thinking of doing this recursively.  I am also using a ORM tool to access the data and create the objects that will be children of the parent
Here is the table I structure I currently use...

```
ORGANIZATION_ID   | Name  |  PARENT_ID
--------------------------------------------------
1                 | A     |     0   -Indicates root
2                 | B     |     1
3                 | C     |     2
4                 | D     |     2
5                 | E     |     4
6                 | F     |     1
7                 | G     |     1
8                 | H     |     7
9                 | J     |     8
10                | K     |     9
```

I'm thinking when I get the org_ID I would look for its parent...
I would then do a search for all rows who's parentID is the orgID.
On each of those you would need to do the same.  I would do that while
the orgID is not the original one searched.
Does that sound right to you?  What is the best way to implement that?
Recursion is definitely going to occur here.  I just need to figure out how.

Comment: Are you trying to gather the data using SQL or JPA? If using JPA, the provider should handle most of this for you once you correctly model your tables.